# Sidestep Devise "You are already logged in." error with Namespaced custom controllers and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875403/only-allow-admin-user-to-create-new-users-in-rails-with-devise-no-external-modu) explains how to let users make other users in devise. I've got it almost figured out, thanks to the answer provided in that article by [Adam Waselnuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3095868/adam-waselnuk) except I can't figure out how to create the same result with *namespaced* controllers and views. I get one of two errors, depending on how my routes.rb is set up... either `Routing Error, No route matches [PUT] "/users/new"` or

My code is below.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :admin do
    resources :users, except: :create
  end
    post 'users/new' => 'admin/users#new', as: :create_user

  resources :shows
  resources :posts
  resources :global_posts

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: "users/registrations",
    }


  root 'pages#home'

  get 'pages/home'
  get 'admin' => 'admin#index', as: :admin
end
```

admin/users_controller.rb

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /admin/users
  # GET /admin/users.json
  def index
    @all_users = User.all
  end

  def show
  end

  # GET /admin/users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /admin/users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /admin/users
  # POST /admin/users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /admin/users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /admin/users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /admin/users/1
  # DELETE /admin/users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(
      :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
      )
    end
end
```

And finally, the admin/users/new.html.erb

```
<h2>New User</h2>

<%= form_for @user, url: create_user_path, html: { method: :put } do |f| %>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.submit "Create New User" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route should be

```
post 'users' => 'admin/users#create', as: :create_user
```

Then you can create the user in

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  @user.save
end
```

Comment: This is great! But I still have an issue: when I click to submit the new user form, it redirects to the Devise edit user page, which just edits the currently signed in user...

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix that issue? I want to refrain from asking a new question... @Nicolas Maloeuvre