# Only the first user/admin should create users with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking for a solution that does not involve an extra library/module, only Devise. How can I make the admin the only one who can create new users?

I have my model Users, created by the Devise, and I included the column Admin (boolean) with the default value set to false. After that, I generated the devise controllers with this command:

`rails generate devise:controllers Users`

But now I don't know what to do really...

I already found some stackoverflow questions that are quite similar, but none answered my question. I'm trying to accomplish this without generating a new controller, only using the subclass generated by the command above. Hope you can help me.

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

I want to do something similar to the last answer of this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875403/only-allow-admin-user-to-create-new-users-in-rails-with-devise-no-external-modu?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but I can't put that to work :/

Comment: you need to create views and make sure that only admin have access to those pages by using something like `gem 'pundit'` or `gem 'cancancan'`. Try something of that and update your question

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create your custom controller as such, in routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers
[Override devise registrations controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)

Then you should run a migration to add an admin field to your user table:

```
def change
  add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false
end
```

And finally in your controller logic, allow only the admin to create user, for instance:

```
if user.admin == false
  flash[:alert] = "You are not allowed to create a user"
  redirect_to whatever_path
end
```

I think this should do the job.

Comment: thank you for your answer. What I want is something like the last answer of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875403/only-allow-admin-user-to-create-new-users-in-rails-with-devise-no-external-modu?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa  - but I can't put that to work properly, maybe you can tweak it a bit, dunno..

Comment: You're welcome, well the last answer of this post looks quite elegant to me, not sure why it doesn't work in your case, no time to test/tweak it for now unfortunately. But note also that you can restrain access to the user creation page to anyone who is not an admin (and not signed in), with a similar logic in the controller related to this view, something like "unless user.admin"   flash message "not allowed" and redirect. That would be a first step. For the rest, I think my solution would work but the other one seems nice, hope you manage to make either of them work for you.

Comment: Thank you again. I end up using the other answer, the problem was that I needed to create a custom controller. Best regards ;)

Comment: Great to hear you made it! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I end up solving my problem with the last answer of this question (Nuclearmans): [Only allow admin user to create new users in Rails with Devise (No external modules)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875403/only-allow-admin-user-to-create-new-users-in-rails-with-devise-no-external-modu?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

BTW, I had to create a custom controller (`registration`).